# select table from unknown database

Tags: sql, database

I have two databases (say Old and In_Use), each with different tables. Tables in In_Use db are move after a while to Old db, and new tables are created in In_Use db.

In a form, I have TableName as input, and want to select items from the selected table. But I do not know in which db that table is (because it changes over time)!

From another post I got the following

```
$Old = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$In_Use = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('Old', $Old);
mysql_select_db('In_Use', $In_Use);
```

This code connects to the two databases.

My question: is there a way to "virtually join" this two dbs, so that I can get items from a table that is either in Old or in In_Use?

```
mysql_query('select * from TableName', $TheTwoDBs);
```

Comment: No way that I am aware of.  And don't use the `mysql_*()` functions, they're deprecated.

Comment: Maybe try both one after another, if first didn't throw an exception, return gathered selection, and if it did, select from second.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES table.
It contains information (table name, schema, rows number, collation, storage engine, etc) for all system/user tables and views, in different databases.

This will return the names of the databases where the table 'stackoverflow_table' exists (there might be more than one databases, feel free to refine)

```
SELECT table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
AND TABLE_NAME='stackoverflow_table'
```

After you have identified the database of the table, use the appropriate connection to the desired database.